# Typeorm query on ManyToMany relations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, typeorm, query-builder

I'm trying to query over the table products to find, Certain products that have "at least" Category "Food", "Cold".

I hope someone can give me a hand to be able to query for 2 or more Categories
I'm able to make it dynamic but I'm struggling hard on the queryBuilder

```html
@Entity()
export class Product{
    @Property()
    @ManyToMany(() => Category, category=> category.products)
    @JoinTable({
        name: "product_category",
        joinColumn: {
            name: "product",
            referencedColumnName: "Id"
        },
        inverseJoinColumn: {
            name: "category",
            referencedColumnName: "Id"
        }
    })
    categories: Category[];
    }
```

```html
@Entity()
export class Category {
    @Property()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    Id: string;

    @Column()
    @Property()
    name: string;

    @Property()
    @ManyToMany(() => LibraryItems, libraryItem => libraryItem.categories)
    products: Product[];
}
```

I have tried using this:
`query.where("categories.name IN(:...name1) AND categories.name IN(:...name2)", { name1: "Food", name2: "Cold" })`

Comment: try this `query.where("categories.name IN (:listnames)", { listnames: ["Food","Cold"] })`

Comment: Also tried but it sometimes fails and gives me items with only "food", i have also experienced problems where choosing " food" and "cold" respectively returns items different from if i choose "cold" and "food" respectively

Comment: Check my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468111/typeorm-find-row-by-array-of-ids-of-another-table-but-all-values-in-this-array-m/72481649#72481649), don't hesitate if still have a problem with it.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but i dont want only those exact 2 categories i want at least to have those 2 categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discuss. this is an example of the query will be:

```
    ...select(["count(categories.name) as count","o.*"]) 
             // count(categories.name) here to get total of categories
    .where('categories.name in (:...categories)',{categories})
            // filter by user ids we need
    .groupBy('product.id')
    .having("count = :count", {count:categories.length})
           // here we check if the products has the categories we want 
    .getRawMany();
```

*PS: as you mentioned in the comment this question will return the rows with at least the categories wanted*

**FOR GLOBAL EXAMPLE WITH MYSQL QUERY** *using W3SCHOOL DATABASE*  [Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/mySQl/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner)

```
SELECT o.*,count(o.OrderID) as total FROM OrderDetails as o join Products as p  on o.ProductId = p.ProductID where o.ProductID in (11) group by o.OrderID having total = 3;
```