# typeorm find row by array of ids of another table but all values in this array must be present in one relation

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on a chatting app.

I have table messages_thread:

```
@Entity("messages_thread")
export class MessagesThreadEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn({
        type: 'bigint',
        name: 'id',
    })
    id: number;

    @OneToMany(type => MessagesThreadUsersEntity, a=> a.thread)
    users!: MessagesThreadUsersEntity[];

    constructor(init?: Partial<MessagesThreadEntity>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

And table messages_thread_users

```
@Entity("messages_thread_users")
export class MessagesThreadUsersEntity {

    @PrimaryColumn({
        type: 'bigint',
        name: 'id',
    })
    id: number;

    @Column("bigint", {
        nullable: false,
        name: 'user_id',
    })
    user_id: number;

    @Column("bigint", {
        nullable: false,
        name: 'thread_id',
    })
    thread_id: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => MessagesThreadEntity, a => a.users)
    @JoinColumn({
        name: 'thread_id',
        referencedColumnName: 'id'
    })
    thread!: MessagesThreadEntity;

    constructor(init?: Partial<MessagesThreadUsersEntity>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use createQueryBuilder to do a complicated query where I need to get the thread that has users matched to the 'user_ids' array. But there is a catch, this thread should have all these users I'm looking for, no more or fewer users.

example:
I'm looking for the thread that has user_ids = [1,2,5], and I have these threads:

- thread A has users [1,2,3,4,5,6]
- thread B has users [2,5]
- thread C has users [1,2,5]

In this case, I want thread C to be returned from the database.

NOT thread A since it has more users than [1,2,5]

NOT thread B since it does not have all the users that I want.

I need the thread that has exactly the array I'm looking for, which is thread C.

What I did so far:

```
  let threadUsers = await this.messagesThreadUsersRepo.createQueryBuilder() 
 .select() 
 .where('affiliate_id IN (:...allUserIds)', { allUserIds }) 
 .getMany();
```

NOTE: I am using NestJs, and the database is MySQL

Comment: Could please share your code to see your effort

Comment: currently I do this

let threadUsers = await this.messagesThreadUsersRepo.createQueryBuilder()
            .select()
            .where('affiliate_id IN (:...allUserIds)', { allUserIds })
            .getMany();

Then just go through the array manually by code, I want to improve the performance by doing it in the query instead in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

To get the wanted result, you have to use the **HAVING** clause because we should specify a condition for filtering values using a function in MySQL used to concatenate data from multiple rows into one field (*GROUP_CONCAT*).

```
 const ids= allUserIds.sort((a, b) => b - a).toString();
 return await this.messagesThreadUsersRepo.createQueryBuilder() 
    .select(["GROUP_CONCAT(user_id ORDER BY user_id DESC) as ids ","o.*"]) 
             // GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) here to get all the user ids by thread 
    .groupBy('thread_id')
    .having(`ids = '${ids}'`)
           // here we check if thread has the exact ids we want 
    .getRawMany();
```

**FOR GLOBAL EXAMPLE WITH MYSQL QUERY** *using W3SCHOOL DATABASE*  [Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/mySQl/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_join_inner)

```
  SELECT o.*,GROUP_CONCAT(p.ProductID) as childs FROM OrderDetails as o 
  join Products as p on o.ProductID = p.ProductID GROUP BY o.OrderID
   HAVING childs = '11';
```

Comment: thank you so much for going beyond to solve my question. The problem is that using "in" in the "where" clause will return rows that has these ids only, even if the thread has more users in it. In this case it returned any thread that has these users, I need the overlap option between messages_thread_users.users and allUserIds.

Comment: have you tried the solution? because for the first point you mentioned, we use ` .having("count = :count", {count:allUserIds.length}) ` you can the the global example and play it, to undrstand

Comment: Yes I tried it and it returned both thread A and C in my example.

Comment: check the answer, I edited with your desire

Comment: OMG! You're a genius! Thank you so much! This worked and now my code is optimized! I learned so much from you. I will learn more about complicated SQL query after delivering this project. You sir are a life saver! Thank you.

Comment: Happy for you, don't hesitate if you have any other questions!